# changing td's color with if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use `if`-statement to change `<td>`-s color.

Basically, I have a simple query to retrieve information from the database. 
Additionaly, I have a column there which keeps the information like if the task is accomplished or not. When I retrieve the information I get all of them, but I need the accomplished tasks to be green, and others without any color.

I've searhed for the answer, but I couldn't find anything that satisfies me.

For example:

---

```
$qry = mysql_query("select * from table");
$recs = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
$recs[]=$row;
mysql_free_result($qry);
```

---

I've tried to add while statement to the code above, but I was confused and it didnt work :(

I'm printing the results using heredoc:
How to give them color here?

---

```
<?php 
$last_id=0;
foreach($recs as $rec)
{   
    $html=<<<HTML
<tr>
<td><b>Номер</b></td>
<td>$rec[0]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Номер документа</b></td>
<td>$rec[1]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Дата регистрации</b></td>
<td>$rec[8]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>От кого</b></td>
<td>$rec[2]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>По</b></td>
<td>$rec[4]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Краткое содержание</b></td>
<td>$rec[3]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Исполнитель</b></td>
<td>$rec[5]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Срок исполнения</b></td>
<td>$rec[6]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Срок исполнения продлен до</b></td>
<td><b>$rec[10]</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Прислан</b></td>
<td>$rec[9]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Примечание</b></td>
<td>$rec[7]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#838B83">&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#838B83">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
HTML;
    print $html;        
    if($rec[0]>$last_id)
        $last_id=$rec[0];
};
$new_id=$last_id+1;
?>
```

---

Comment: Where is the HTML being output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use ternary operator, rather than using IF statement, or your could use another workaround to use arrays to define colors, this would help you to define various colors for each status value globally, please find an example below:

```
$aryColor = array(
 'complete' => 'green',
 'incomplete' => "red",
 'pending' => 'orange'
 .....
);
//you can specify values for all of your status, or leave them blank for no color, the keys in the array are the possible values from your status field
foreach($recs as $rec) {
 echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$aryColor[$rec['status_field']].'">
 <td>'.$rec['title_field'].'</td>
 </tr>';
}
```

I hope this helps you out, and you can easily edit this for HEREDOC.

Comment: I guess I understood your code, and what you've meant. But I couldn't make it in my code :( Look, I've wrote smth like this: `$qry=mysql_query("select * from table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    if($row['completed']==1){
      $status_field='complete';
    } else{
      $status_field='incomplete';
    } 
 }
$recs=array();
$count=mysql_num_rows($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
$recs[]=$row;
mysql_free_result($qry);

$aryColor = array(
 'complete' => 'green',
 'incomplete' => "red",
);`

Comment: `completed` is a column, which means if it equals to 1 it is completed.

Comment: @Patrick you can change the array as follows:

    `$aryColor = array(
     0 => "red", //signifies incomplete
     1 => "green" //signifies complete
    );`

Comment: yes array thingy is working, I've made like you said, and I've checked it, so if I put 0 in the `<tr bgcolor='$aryColor[0]'>` it becomes red, if 1 then it becomes green. My problem is that it can identify the status_field :(

Comment: @patrick, i got you, here what i could suggest for you, based on the field information you have provided earlier:
`$aryColor[$rec['completed']]`

Answer (score 5):

rather than colour use a class, so you can change it in CSS

```
<td<?php if($row['complete']) echo ' class="complete"'; ?>>data</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>column heading</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $qry=mysql_query("select * from table");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        if($row['urcolumnn']==1)
        {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=green>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        ?>

        <td>
            <?php echo $row['urcolumn']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

This is an example code. think this will help you. here i give the background color to `<tr>` like this if u want to give color to `<td>` use this `<td style="background-color:green;">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, what `if($row['urcolumn']==1)` means?

Comment: you have to make green color based on a condition right. so i just add a example condition like if that value is 1(its only an example) put green color else some other color. i added this for easy understanding. and now i think its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

first you should change your column values change its structure to int and set default value as "0".so when your task is complete the field value should be change to "1".

now come to your code:

```
$qry = mysql_query("select * from table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    if($row['status']==1){
     echo "<td color="green">Data</td>"
    }
    else{
       echo "<td color="white">Data</td>";
    } 
 }
```

Hence you can get the rows in green which status is==1 means complete and white for incomplete.

Comment: I guess it would work If I've printed results right there, since I'm using heredoc, I can't do that :(

Comment: you can do this by using function,make a new function on this file and return my sql resource id and call this function on the file where you are out putting this HTML.definitely it works